# Trackbar value displayed in textbox C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Using C# and WinForms, I am trying to display a trackbar value in a textbox. I thought it would be simple enough, and I used the code from the Microsoft Visual studio website. However it simply doesn't work. Here is the code I have:

```
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // Display the trackbar value in the text box.
            textBox1.Text = "" + trackBar1.Value;

        }
```

If it makes a difference, the trackbar is getting its min/max values from numeric up down boxes, changeable by the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try putting your code into the [ValueChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.valuechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event handler instead.
Now you seem to use the scroll event, which fires when the user uses scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `ToString()` method.
 
`Value` returns an `int` and `text` property must be set with string value.
 (you have a design time error).

```
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = trackBar1.Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Even if the value coming across is still an integer?

Comment: `trackBar1.Value` is always an integer, the c# compiler will not execute this code without useing `ToString()`, because c# is very strongly typed, if you will use VB.NET for example there will be no error because the compiler will do the casting for you. BTW, MSDN examples use the `Scroll` event: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.scroll(v=vs.110).aspx